# What is an "INCLUDE" dispatch in DispatcherServlet?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, exception, error-handling

### Question

What is an "INCLUDE" dispatch from `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet`?

### How It Occurs

Caused when my custom implementation of `javax.servlet.Filter` throws an exception *after* the request processing is complete:

```java
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {
        logger.debug("My pre-processing happens here...");

        chain.doFilter(request, response); // request processing by @RestController happens here
    } finally {
        logger.error("Exception thrown here!");
        throw new CustomException("My custom error message");
    }
}
```

### Example Logs

```
[2019.03.13 19:58:19.566] [DEBUG] 11148 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-7] m.RequestFilter                            : My pre-processing happens here...
[2019.03.13 19:58:19.570] [DEBUG] 11148 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-7] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                  : GET "/resource", parameters={}
[2019.03.13 19:58:19.574] [ERROR] 11148 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-7] m.RequestFilter                            : Exception thrown here!
[2019.03.13 19:58:19.578] [ERROR] 11148 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]        : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

m.CustomException: My custom error message
    at m.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:18) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]

[2019.03.13 19:58:19.590] [DEBUG] 11148 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-7] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                  : "INCLUDE" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
[2019.03.13 19:58:19.594] [DEBUG] 11148 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-7] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity m.CustomErrorController.handleError(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
[2019.03.13 19:58:19.594] [ERROR] 11148 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-7] m.CustomErrorController                    : HTTP Error: OK (200), Servlet Name: dispatcherServlet, Request URI: /resource, Exception: m.CustomException: My custom error message
[2019.03.13 19:58:19.594] [DEBUG] 11148 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-7] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor    : Found 'Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8' in response
[2019.03.13 19:58:19.598] [DEBUG] 11148 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-7] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor    : Writing ["{"path":"/resource","error":"OK","message":"My custom error message","timestamp":"2019.03.13 19:58:19.594","status":200}"]
[2019.03.13 19:58:19.598] [DEBUG] 11148 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-7] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                  : Exiting from "INCLUDE" dispatch, status 200
```

### API Response

The returned response is correct though. It seems the original non-error response for the requested `/resource` is returned *before* the error-handling happens, because the exception is thrown after request processing. And only after that, the "INCLUDE" dispatch is generated and mapped to my custom implementation of the `ErrorController`.

But if ...

1. ... the correct response is already sent, ...
2. ... and the exception is mapped to my custom `ErrorController`, ...

... then **why on earth is the response code not some type of error, and instead 200 OK as the original response?**

Comment: Did this get resolved if so how?